# Edit R Makevars file to get STAN to work and use Rccp and compile C++

Tags: c++, macos, unix, stan, rcpparmadillo

Is it possible to change the Makevars file?  I am [told on the STAN forums](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/unable-to-get-stan-working-with-r-3-5-1-and-catalina-10-15-2/12831/21) that I need to do this to get Rccp to work as well.  When I try to change it, I am locked out and it saves it as a different file name.  How can I override this?

To be more specific:

I need to change the file from this:

```
  # clang: start
    CFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
    CCFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
    CXXFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
    CPPFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include

    SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS+=-Wl,-rpath,${R_HOME}/lib ${R_HOME}/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib
    # clang: end
```

To this:

```
# clang: start
CFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CCFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CXXFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CPPFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include

CXX14FLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CPPF14LAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include

SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS+=-Wl,-rpath,${R_HOME}/lib ${R_HOME}/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib

SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS+=-Wl,-rpath,${R_HOME}/lib ${R_HOME}/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib
# clang: end
```

When I open the file in text editor, I see this at the top:

[image]
When I manually edit this, it will not save as the original file name and makes a duplicate with this:

[image]

Comment: It will depend on the security features of your unstated OS.

Comment: This is moving out of the territory of R, and into general Unix/command line skills (I assume you're on Mac OS). You'll want to do things like `ls -l ~/.R/Makevars` to check the file permissions, maybe `sudo nano ~/.R/Makevars` to edit it etc., all of this is a bit hard to address in a SO question.

Comment: @42- Hi, yes I am on a mac os.  I will change the tagging

Comment: You need to tell us how experienced you are with Terminal command line operations. Can you show us the contents of the file? Where is it? What are the exact operations that you are attempting and the exact error messages? (don't ever remember an OS messages saying "you are locked out".)

Comment: Hi 42, I can use the terminal, I have sort of introductionary experience in that I can ssh into clusters, move files around and delete them, but I don't have sysadmin skills.

Comment: sudo command helped, thank you!

Comment: I was under the impression that the recommended (by Simon Urbanek) clang and fortran compilers were available here: https://cran.r-project.org//bin/macosx/tools